# How to execute a file in separate gnome terminal in linux

Tags: gnome-terminal

I want to execute a C program in a separate terminal, I've tried this command

```
gnome-terminal -x ./test
```

and

```
gnome-terminal -e test
```

But it opens a new terminal and before giving me output, it just vanishes. How could I solve this issue using genome-terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Put your app in a script and add `read` at the end.

test.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
./test
read
```

don't forget to add executable permission to your script

Answer (score 0):

If you want terminal to stay opened after command execution then just run some shell in it, e.g.:

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'test; bash'
```